# How does one pass numeric variables in QXMLStreamWriter functions?

Tags: c++, qt

I am using a QXMLStreamWriter class to write data to an XML file. When dealing with variables that contain numeric values and passing them to the writeTextElement() function before converting them to a string using QString(), I get undesired results.

Comment: Please show the code giving undesired results. Usually one would use QString::number().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [QString::number()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number) is the correct way to do this.

```
int numVar = 10;
QString nameVar = "elementName";
xmlStreamWriter.WriteTextElement(nameVar, QString::number(numVar));
```